# Adding Events Handlers to fullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to add events on header (agendaWeek view) and on the day-number in Month view.
I did this:

```
$(".fc-day-number").click(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});

$(".fc-widget-header").click(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

But its not working. But when I add mouseover instead of click event, it works

```
$(".fc-day-number").mouseover(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});

$(".fc-widget-header").mouseover(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it has something to do with the built in dayClick or select callbacks. Try using "mousedown()" instead and see what happens.